# JHipster Spring Boot where is package name used ComponentFind set?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

How do I adjust package name in @ComponentFind for JHipster? I renamed some packages and now I am getting error that it does not find any bean CustomAuditEventRepository required a bean of type 'com.mynewpackagename.repository.PersistenceAuditEventRepository' that could not be found. Consider defining one. Well there never was a Bean defined for this so I assume its a problem with package name scanned by @ComponentFind but I cannot see exactly where to set this it seems like its in config but I am not sure exactly where to set this. Doing a search I dont see a packageName set to new or old value.

I tried changing package name in .yo-rc.json

```
   "packageName": "com.mycompany.newpackagename",
   "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/newpackagename",
```

But that does not seem to solve the issue. Where do I check if this bean was generated or not. How do I kick off bean generaton? I am running with ./mvnw

Comment: When you changed package name in .yo-rc.json, you re-generated the app after, right?

Comment: No I did not regenerate the whole app. Whats the process for doing that with and existing app?

Comment: Yes, this is the right step is to regenerate the app being careful to save copy of all files that get overwritten